# Rotating an image nuisance

Tags: java, image, swing, java-2d, image-rotation

Alright guys i'm trying to make an Asteroids type game and I need to be able to rotate an image around so that the front of the ship follows my mouse. I have looked for a few hours now and have found a couple of things but none that satisfy my needs.

If anyone knows how to do this please share!

thanks in advance

here is the code i have now

```
package Asteroids;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class Asteroids extends JFrame implements Runnable, MouseListener,
            MouseMotionListener, KeyListener {

        private Image dbImage;
        private Graphics dbg;
        int x, y, mx, my;
        int a, b, c, degree;
        double scale = 1.0;
        ImageIcon shipIcon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                .getResource("AstroidsShip.png"));
        Image ship = shipIcon.getImage();

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Asteroids frame = new Asteroids();
            Thread thread = new Thread(frame);
            thread.start();
        }

        public Asteroids() {
            addMouseListener(this);
            addMouseMotionListener(this);
            addKeyListener(this);

            setTitle("Astroids");
            setSize(500, 500);
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            setResizable(false);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);

            x = getWidth() / 2 - 10;
            y = getHeight() - getHeight() / 2;
        }

        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
            dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
            paintComponent(dbg);
            g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.drawString("POS: " + mx + ", " + my, 10, 40);
            System.out.println(getAngle());
            g.drawImage(ship, x, y, this);
            g.drawLine(x + 12, y + 10, mx, my);
            repaint();
        }

        public int getAngle() {
            a = mx - (x + 12);
            b = (y - 10) - my;
            return degree = (int) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(b, a));
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            mx = e.getX();
            my = e.getY();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: This guy might help you: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wWLEeQSXLQ&feature=relmfu

Comment: I just watched that video and I already know how to move objects like that. What I need to do is rotate my image, the ship, so that the front of it is always looking at the mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Java2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html). It allows to rotate the image and do a lot lot of other cool operations on the image. It also have got hardware acceleration support (through DirectX or OpenGL).

Java2D is built-in in JRE.

Comment: I would but the problem is i'm not sure how to use 2D. I just started learning Java and I code something called XliteRSPS http://www.xlitersps.com it's a RuneScape Private server so I don't really deal with the graphics because they are all in the game client.

Comment: Here's some sample code: http://www.javareference.com/jrexamples/viewexample.jsp?id=88 - it'll work with Graphics class that you use already in your game.

Comment: Alright I kinda sorta figured out how to use it. The problem I am having now is that it's rotating clockwise when I go around it counter-clockwise. Do you know if there is a way to make it rotate the other way or a unit circle would?

Answer (score 2):

Inside your paintComponent method, you could make the code look like:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawString("POS: " + mx + ", " + my, 10, 40);
    System.out.println(getAngle());
    Graphics2D g2d = new (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.translate(X, Y);
    g2d.rotate(DEGREES);
    g2d.drawImage(ship, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, this); 
    g.drawLine(x + 12, y + 10, mx, my);
    repaint();
}
```

For more complex use, you could create a method with all of your ship drawing calculations:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawString("POS: " + mx + ", " + my, 10, 40);
    System.out.println(getAngle());
    drawShip(g);
    g.drawLine(x + 12, y + 10, mx, my);
    repaint();
}

public void drawShip(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.translate(X, Y);
    g2d.rotate(DEGREES);
    g2d.drawImage(ship, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, this);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use a rotate instance from one of [the methods of `AffineTransform`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#method_summary) that accepts anchors for the X,Y co-ordinates.

Comment: @trashgod Hey.. how can asteroids appear in the middle of the field?  Not fair!  Fun though.. ;)

Comment: Energy shield left as an exercise. :-)